# Struts2 tag giving jasper exception

Tags: java, struts2, ognl

Below is the jsp code

```
<ul class="nav pull-right">
          <s:if test="%{curUser != null}">
              <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">%{curUser.userName}<b class="caret"></b></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                  <s:if test="%{curUser.admin eq true}">
                    <li><a href="/admin" title="Admin Section"><i class="icon-certificate"></i> Admin</a></li>
                  </s:if>
                  <li><a href="/user/%{curUser.userName}" title="%{curUser.userName}'s Profile"><i class="icon-user"></i> Profile</a></li>
                  <li><a href="/user/profile.html?action=edit"><i class="icon-cog"></i> Edit Profile</a></li>
                  <li><a href="/login.html?action=logout"><i class="icon-off"></i> Sign out</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
            </s:if>
            <s:else>
              <li><a href="/login">Login</a></li>
              <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
              <li><a href="/signup">Sign Up</a></li>
            </s:else>
        </ul>
```

I'm getting this error. Need help with this.

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /decorators/base.jsp at line 45

42:               </a></li>
43:             </ul>
44:             <ul class="nav pull-right">
45:               <s:if test="%{curUser != null}">
46:                   <li class="dropdown">
47:                     <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">%{curUser.userName}<b class="caret"></b></a>
48:                     <ul class="dropdown-menu">
```

here is my web.xml configuration - I guess problem is using Struts tags with sitemesh.

```
   <filter>
    <filter-name>sitemesh</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.opensymphony.sitemesh.webapp.SiteMeshFilter</filter-class>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>sitemesh</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>

  <filter>
    <filter-name>LoginCheckFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.tutorial.filter.LoginCheckFilter</filter-class>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>LoginCheckFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/admin</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/admin/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>

  <filter>
    <filter-name>UrlRewriteFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>logLevel</param-name>
      <param-value>WARN</param-value>
    </init-param>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>UrlRewriteFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>

  <filter>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>actionPackages</param-name>
      <param-value>com.tutorial.action</param-value>
    </init-param>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
  </filter-mapping>

  <listener>
    <listener-class>
      org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    </listener-class>
  </listener>

  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.listener.StrutsListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
```

Comment: Is `curUser` present in the Value Stack?

Comment: Are other Struts2 jsps rendering properly?

Comment: Use tag <s:debug/> make sure that curUser object is available in valuestack. Or remove (if-else) block if page is rendering properly problem is curUser not available in the valueStack.

Comment: show the full stacktrace... ordinarly you should be able to reference something that does not exist on the valuestack without it doing what it's doing... How it is generating a JasperException from mearly accessing curUser makes me want to know what getCurUser looks like... or if there is some spring/AOP magic happening.

Answer (score 0):

It was happening the same to me, and touching i was also receiving another error.
What happens is that the struts tags arent replaced on runtime, so it cant be compiled by the html processor.
The solution is that in web.xml, the struts filter mapping MUST be upper than the sitemesh filter mapping.

I was answered for the same in this topic:
[s:url not replaced on decorator sitemesh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16811509/surl-not-replaced-on-decorator-sitemesh)

take a look for if it sounds familiar to you.